# DB Table of constants vs constants in code

Tags: php, mysql, constants

Eternal question.

I have a table moments_of_day:

```
id name
1  Morning
2  Afternoon
3  Evening
4  Night
```

And then an other table, meals, references it with moments_of_day_id.

And then, in my PHP code I want to get all meals of morning.

What's the best option? Should I repeat constants in my PHP MomentsOfDay model doing something like next code?

```
const MORNING = 1;
```

By repeating constants I think it can be dangerous. If in the future the table changes I also have to add it to the MomentsOfDay model.

What do you think?

Comment: You could query your table of constants and dynamically define your constants in PHP. But in general I think relying on MySQL auto_inc values in your application logic is dangerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is necessarily a deterministic answer for this question, but you should be sure to settle on a solution that doesn't just trust that the php and mysql align. I would define the constants however you want in php and then use some real data about them to look up a record in mysql. If you assert `const MORNING = 1;` in your php, then `1` becomes a real part of your data model and should be stored in mysql as such. You can still create `AUTO_INC` values in mysql, but those should be considered implementation artifacts and not application data. I wouldn't think of this problem as being any different than other parts of your model (e.g., users, permissions, schedules, etc). You are creating a data model in PHP and using mysql to make it persistent. You send your model data to mysql to persist it, and you use that same model data to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

In your case more suitable the enum type.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html

```
field_name ENUM('Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Evening', 'Night');
```

Comment: ENUMs are good if you only have a single column. If you have identical ENUMs in multiple tables, the maintenance can get annoying because you have to update multiple tables if the ENUM changes.

Comment: In that case no matter where you put constants or some else. If you want get some data by constant from database and this data can varying, you doing some thing wrong. May be you need to create a configuration file if this is default value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't want to use ENUM. Basically for this reasons: http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/